# Hibernate Cache Annotation region attribute doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, caching, attributes, annotations, region

I have a spring/springwebflow (app A) application that uses Hibernate second level cache and also query cache. The application only reads from a database, not add/update/delete statements are possible.

The queries are being cached to one region called "daoCache". I have set this by an annotation on namedQuerys

I have the entity with an annotation from Hibernate @Cache with the attribute region set for "daoCache" too

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUP_OPERATOR")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GROUP_OPERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_GROUP_OPERATOR")
@NamedQueries( {
@NamedQuery(name = "findGroupOperatorByMaster", query = "FROM GroupOperator groupOperator WHERE groupOperator.segment IS NULL and groupOperator.pointsMaster.pointMaster like ?",
    hints={@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheRegion", value="daoCache"),
       @QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheable", value="true")})
})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "daoCache")
public class GroupOperator implements Serializable{
 ....
```

Besides this I have another application (app B) that connects to the same database and perform add/updates/deletes over the same database

For this reason we have set a limit of 20 minutes to refresh the cache region on the app A. So changes made in app B are reflected in app A after 20 minutes.

So lets suppose app A perform a query "select * from  group_operator where point_master = 1000". That query will be saved in cache with the result identifier, let's say groupOperator#1. So any other time (between 20 minutes) that that query executes it will return, from the cache, the identifier #1. And the entity will also be saved in the same cache region.

The problem is when app B deletes a record and create a new one (with a different ID), ***but* *with the same values used as parameters in the query***

So, between the 20 minutes the app A will return the entity groupOperator#1 and no select statements are shown in the app log. This is the expected behavior.

After 20 minutes the cache will be reset.

Now App A attempts to execute this same query ("select * from group_operator where point_master = 1000"). It will do the query over the database, because the cached was cleaned after 20 minutes. So the result should be the new ID, created in App B. But instead of that I'm getting an ObjectNotFoundException No row with the given identifier exists: groupOperator#1

Even the select statements are shown on the log but still returning the old entity identifier. And of course the ID 1 is no longer in the database.

It's very weird because I thought that cleaning the cache will perform the query again

If both entity and query are cached in the same region why is still looking for the old entity?

After a few days investigating this, using heap dumps, I found that the entity is not being cached on the "daoCache" specified on the @Cache annotation. But is being cached on a new region named "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.groupOperator". Seems that the attribute for that annotation doesn't work.

I have a couple of questions

1-Why the region attribute in the Cache Annotation is not working? Even i set "daoCache" is beign saved in another one? is this a bug from hibernate?

2-How exactly the query cache works? I mean, if the query is executed again then it should return the new identifier, and then with that new identifier hibernate should execute the load method and problem solved. But still trying to load from the old identifier.

This is my actual ehcache.xml configuration

```
<cache name="daoCache" maxElementsInMemory="30000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true">
    </cache>

    <cache name="rwCache" maxElementsInMemory="30000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true">
    </cache>

    <cache name="xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.groupOperator" maxElementsInMemory="30000"     eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true">
    </cache>
```

This my cache provider

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
```

Using following version of hibernate

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations
    </artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

*Thanks for your time*

**UPDATE:**

I didn't specify any hibernate.cache.region.factory_class. So I guess is using the default one. Don't know which one is the default

The queries has the annotation queryhint in the Class. That is working well, is caching the query, even if I delete all the records from the table is still returning the old record without executing any select on the DB. So query cache works great.

The problems is:...

After deleting all the records on the table and verifying that query cache works I added a new record to the same table with the same values as before but different primary ID

After clearing the cache (automatically after 20 minutes) the query is executed again over the database(which is ok and I can see that select statements in the log). The new record in the table is found, and that should return an identifier to then load the whole Entity into memory. The weird thing is that when it tries to get the whole Entity into memory is looking for that entity using the old identifier, not the new one that I added before. Is like if the query, even is executed again over the database, is still returning the old identifier. But I repeat, the query cache is working as normal in other scenarios and that's for sure.

So, I don't understand how query cache and entity cache works together. Is like a problem between the query cache and the entity cache. I'm saying this because I solved this by adding in ehcache.xml the region configuration for that Entity.

```
<cache
    name="com.citi.latam.business.services.dao.model.db.campaign.groupOperator"
    maxElementsInMemory="30000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120"
    timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true">
</cache>
```

Answer (score 3):

FIXED!

I finally solved.
First, what I did was to enable all the debug from hibernate and ehcache

Searching in the logs I found a no proper configuration of my Database Model

Object GroupOperator has a property called Calendar.
The problem was that object Calendar also has a List of GroupOperator with the Cache annotation. So each time Hibernate get the new GroupOperator also want to refresh the childs entities like Calendar, but calendar has his own list of GroupOperator and seems that child entities are not in the same cache region or works in a different way.

Problem solved!
Thanks for your time @jhadesdev, was helpfull to keep investigating this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Which `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class`are you using, `EhCacheRegionFactory` or `SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory`? This could relate for point 1.

For point 2, it works as you mention but the queries need to be marked as cacheable separately. In the criteria API this is done with `setCacheable(true)`, and in JPQL with a query hint.

For the problem that the two caches are not in sync, the query cache is not necessarily being evicted at the same time as the cache region where the entity lives.

Queries are by default cached in the default cache region, but its possible to choose the region where the query is cached with the API `criteria.setCacheRegion()`.

By putting the query in question in the same cache region as the entity, this would ensure that both the query cached results and the cached entities are evicted at the same time.

Comment: I answered you with an update in my question. Please take a look. 
Thanks

Comment: I edited the answer for evicting the caches at the same time, but for the select hitting the database and still returning ancient values that is only possible if the delete/insert transaction was not commited, or if an isolation level REPEATABLE_READ/SERIALIZABLE is kept for a huge amount of time (20 minutes) by the service doing the periodic query

Comment: Thanks! In fact I'm doing the delete transaction outside the main application (from App B). So the main app is not aware of the change made from App B. This is the scenario: App A reads, App B deletes record, App B creates new record with same values as the deleted one, but different ID, App A reads again, NotEntityFoundException is thrown. My guess is that hibernate session in App A is not aware of the change in the table so hibernate supose that there was no change at all and still looking for the ancient identifier. Maybe is something to do with UpdateTimestampsCache, will take a look